# Capture msi errors in Installshield 2014 Suite

Tags: windows-installer, installation, installshield, basic-msi

I am writing a Suite installer that installs multiple basic msi's for different feature sets. I am having some issues where one of the msi installs fails because of some dism functions not installing correctly and its rolling back the entire Suite install.

What i want to do is IF one of the msi components fail to install, i want to catch the failure and give the customer the option to either continue the install(without the failed component) or stop/rollback the install so far. I cant figure out how to catch the error codes from the msi inside of the Suite project.

Answer (score 0):

You did not indicate what version of InstallShield Premium you are using. InstallShield has added a lot of functionality since they introduced the project type.

When you add a MSI package, the detection process for a successful install should be all set. After package is installed, the Suite installer test this condition. If it is true, then the install is successful, if not, it fails. It doesn't collect the error code from the MSI.

If what you are really trying to figure out is how to handle failed DISM installs, that will depend on what is failing. For instance there is a known issue where .NET Framework 3.5 will not install on Windows 10 Creators update due to a failure of the DISM call to ever return a value. If you have your own Powershell call or Managed code call to DISM then one approach is to code your custom action to set suite property value and use that as a test for installing packages, displaying messages, etc.

Comment: Updated question - Installshield 2014